# What is bad file descriptor in c?

Tags: c, posix, file-descriptor

This is my code of function that wants to read file:

```
int sendByByte(int filed,int sockfd,int filesize)
{
 int i=0;
 int sent=0;
 char buf[BUFSIZE];
 while(i<filesize)
 {
  printf("fd is : %d\n",filed);
  printf("i: %d\n",i);
  int byte_read=read(filed,buf,BUFSIZE);
  if(byte_read == -1)
  {
   printf("MOSHKEL dar read\n");
   return -1;
  }
  int byte_send=send(sockfd,buf,byte_read,0);
  if(byte_send==-1)
  {
   printf("MOSHKEL dar send\n");
   return -1;
  }
  close(filed);
  i+=byte_read;
  sent+=byte_read;
 }
 return sent;
}
```

The problem is when `i=0` it works and read file but then `read()` returns -1.
What is the problem of the code?

- `socketfd` => server's socket
- `filed` => file descriptor

and I sure that file descriptor is valid.

Comment: wellcome to SO. The question has nothing to do with C by itself, file descriptors are an OS feature. Please change the title and the tags of your question accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

After the first iteration you `close(filed)` (line 22), causing all further reads to fail.
Move the `close` call outside the loop, or even better: Let the caller close the file descriptor, since he opened it.